# How to iterate to 100 using a for or while loop and show the sum of each iteration with javascript?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop, iteration

Just doing a small homework. I need to iterate to 100, but also console.log the result of each previous example.

Example of the series: `(1)+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+…+(1+2+3+…+n)<=100`

```
Iteracion1=1
Iteracion2= 1+2 = 3
iteracion 3: 1+2+3 = 6
iteracion 4: 1+2+3+4 = 10
```

I have this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if(i < 100) {
    console.log(`${i}+${1}`);
   }};
```

But I don't know how to add the sum of it on each iteration. I you have any references for this it would be great! thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `efficiently` achieve the result using a single loop.

For demo purposes, I've printed up to `20`. You can add any number of your choice.

```js
let lastTotal = 0;
let lastStr = "";

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
  const total = (lastTotal ?? 0) + i;
  const str = lastStr ? lastStr + " + " + i : i;
  console.log(`Iteration ${i}: ${str}${total === 1 ? "" : " = " + total}`);
  lastTotal = total;
  lastStr = str;
}
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: A conditional to set first iteration to ***1+2 = 3***:  `i > 1 ? console.log(` ` `Iteration ${i-1}: ${str} = ${total}` ` `) : null;`, wouldn't this fit better as OP's desired outcome? First iteration would only show the 1+2 = 3, yes? Good answer though, nice and compact.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I've updated to ``Iteration ${i}: ${str}${total === 1 ? "" : " = " + total}`` which will handle this case

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to work really well. I'm looking into the code to understand it better. I'm a beginner, so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This should do fine.

I created a new Array for the length of iteration of `i` and use `Array#reduce` to sum it all up to a number.

```js
const max = 10;

for (let i = 1; i <= max; i++) {
  const arr = new Array(i).fill().map((_, i) => i + 1);
  console.log(`Iteration ${i}: ${arr.join('+')} = ${arr.reduce((acc, b) => acc + b, 0)}`);
}
```

Comment: OP want result in `Iteration= 1+2 = 3` format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables outside of for to achieve this

```js
let sum = 0;
const previousSums = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  previousSums.push(sum);
  sum += i;
  console.log(`${previousSums}`);
}
```

Comment: OP want result in `Iteration= 1+2 = 3` format?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array you can add indexes to.
2. Create a function that calculates the sum of the numbers in the array. I've used [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) here.
3. [Create a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and then log it.

```js
const arr = [];

function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((acc, c) => acc + c, 0);
}

// On each iteration push the index in to the
// array. Create a string that joins up the array
// elements and logs the result of the sum
for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  arr.push(i);
  const str = `Iteration ${i}: ${arr.join('+')} = ${sum(arr)}`;
  console.log(str);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var total = 0;
var res = 0;
var upto = 6;
for(i=1;i<=upto;i++){
total = total+i;
res = res+total;
}
console.log(res);
```